# Go programming iota similarity with enum in c++

Tags: c++, go, enums, iota

Pardon me my knowledge in Go is very limited.
I have a definition like this

```
type ErrorVal int
const (
    LEV_ERROR ErrorVal = iota
    LEV_WARNING  
    LEV_DEBUG
)
```

Later in my Go sample code I want to define a value for a type of `ErrorVal`.

What I am trying to do is in C we can define enum value like this

```
enum ErrorVal myVal = LEV_ERROR;
```

How can I do something similar in Go?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following sinppet:

```
myval := LEV_ERROR
```

or

```
var myval ErrorVal = LEV_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a constant to a variable and get the same result as C's `enum`:

```
type ErrorVal int

const (
    LEV_ERROR ErrorVal = iota
    LEV_WARNING
    LEV_DEBUG
)

func main() {
    myval := LEV_ERROR
    fmt.Println(myval)
}
```

[Go by Example](https://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample/public/constants-and-iota.html):

> We can use *iota* to simulate C's enum or #define constant.